# Traefik IngressRoute redirect doesn’t work

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, traefik, traefik-ingress, ingress-route

I have setup following `IngressRoute` for default path and `wp-*`

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: external-1
  namespace: marketing
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
    - websecure
  routes:
    - match: Host(`example.com`) || Host(`www.example.com`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: wordpress
          port: 80
      middlewares:
        - name: https-redirect
  tls:
    secretName: prod-cert
```

and

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: wp-admin-1
  namespace: marketing
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
    - websecure
  routes:
    - match: Host(`example.com`) || Host(`www.example.com`) && PathPrefix(`/wp-login.php`,`/wp-login.php/`, `/wp-admin/`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: wordpress
          port: 80
      middlewares:
        - name: secured-restricted
  tls:
    secretName: prod-cert
```

Middleware :

```
---

apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: secured-restricted
  namespace: marketing
spec:
  chain:
    middlewares:
    - name: https-redirect
    - name: permited-ips

---

apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: https-redirect
  namespace: marketing
spec:
  redirectScheme:
    scheme: https
    permanent: true

---

apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: permited-ips
  namespace: marketing
spec:
  ipWhiteList:
    sourceRange:
    - #.#.#.#/28

---
```

`https://www.example.com` --> works

`https://example.com` --> Get Forbidden

`https://example.com` works only when I try to access it from whitelisted IP (#.#.#.#/28)

So looks like external-1 IngressRoute is not getting hit.

What is wrong with this setup ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting the rules in following way fixed the issue.

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: external-1
  namespace: marketing
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
    - websecure
  routes:
    - match: Host(`example.com`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: wordpress
          port: 80
    - match: Host(`www.example.com`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: wordpress
          port: 80
      middlewares:
        - name: https-redirect
  tls:
    secretName: prod-cert
```

and

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: wp-admin-1
  namespace: marketing
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
    - websecure
  routes:
    - match: Host(`example.com`) && PathPrefix(`/wp-login.php`,`/wp-login.php/`, `/wp-admin/`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: wordpress
          port: 80
    - match: Host(`www.example.com`) && PathPrefix(`/wp-login.php`,`/wp-login.php/`, `/wp-admin/`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: wordpress
          port: 80
      middlewares:
        - name: secured-restricted
  tls:
    secretName: prod-cert
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot a bracket, and your original configuration might just work by changing to this:

```
(Host(`example.com`) || Host(`www.example.com`)) && PathPrefix(`/wp-login.php`,`/wp-login.php/`, `/wp-admin/`)
```